# Laravel - 404 | Not Found upon "/{id}" entry

Tags: php, laravel, routes, controller

I am getting a "404 | Not Found" error when i try to access a specific item from my database. The items with the specific ID's do exist in the database, but i am not even sure if that even has any influence on the problem.

My routing looks likes this:

```
Route::prefix('departments')->group(function() {
Route::get('/{id}', [DepartmentController::class, 'showDepartment']);
});
```

And the related controller looks like this:

```
public function showDepartment() {
        return '';
    }

}
```

I haven't yet finished the function. I just wanted to check if the routing even worked by returning an empty string.

So what am i doing wrong? Is it the routing or the controller?

Comment: How to check the ID in the control to make sure it is empty or not?

Comment: What is the full URL you're trying to access? Is it Laravels 404 error or the webservers default 404? And no, if the id exists in your database or not doesn't matter since you're not actually checking it.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson It is Laravels 404 error. I am hosting it locally: localhost:8000/departments/{id}

Comment: Do you literally have `{id}` in the URL in the browser? If so, try it with something like `123`.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson No haha. It doesen't matter if i type "/departments/1" (which does exist in the database), or "/departments/100" (which doesn't exist in the database. The error comes up no matter what.

Comment: Run `php artisan route:list` to check if the routes are actually getting registered. Where are these routes declared?

Comment: Update: I resolved the issue, and it turned out that there was a mistake with the URL i tried to access. Therefore no need to change the Model or Controller as someone have mentioned below.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Laravel [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#required-parameters), you have to define the parameter in the route then use it in the controller as a parameter.
in your controller:

```
public function showDepartment($id) {
    return 'Hello';
}
```

The id is not bound to any model to fetch from the database to do that you can use [Laravel route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-model-binding)

for example when you have a model named `Department` you write your route like this:

```
Route::get('/{department}', [DepartmentController::class, 'showDepartment']);
```

and in the controller:

```
public function showDepartment(Department $department) {
    return 'Hello from depratment';
}
```

When your department exists it returns the response otherwise return 404.

Answer (score 0):

You may need a Department model class. Then you can find the item from database by id `$department = Department::findOrFail($id);`

Comment: Why would that be necessary in this case? Just because you have a group it doesn't mean it automatically will try and check the database unless you tell it to.

Answer (score 0):

you are send parameter in route and this function without any parameter
route :

```
Route::prefix('departments')->group(function() {
Route::get('/{id}', [DepartmentController::class, 'showDepartment']);
});
```

your function in controller should be

```
public function showDepartment($id) {

        $department = Department::findOrFail($id);
    }

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the route still work though, just that it won't get the ID without adding it to the method signature?